# What N600 mean in disk_id mean in /dev/disk/by-id/

Tags: linux, hard-drive, udev, ata

I wanted to generate the file names inside the directory `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

with `lsblk` i get

```bsh
$ lsblk -o name,model,serial
NAME    MODEL                 SERIAL
sda     HGST HUHXXXX12AL      XXXXXXXX
```

so i have generated

`/dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HUHXXXX12AL_XXXX`

**BUT** it's wrong

when i list the files, i found: `ata-HGST_HUHXXXX12ALN600_XXXX`

to generate the good id, we can use

```bsh
$ /lib/udev/ata_id /dev/sda 
HGST_HUHXXXX12ALN600_XXXX
```

Does anyone know where the `N600` is from and what does it mean ?

Comment: Guess: `lsblk` has a character limitation for the model field, while `ata_id` etc. don't? So the `N600` was always part of the model, `lsblk` just didn't display it...

Comment: nop, c code seems to use `xmalloc` and not a sized buffer

Comment: But does it shorten on output? Which method does it use to get the model name? What happens if you use sg3-tools and directly ask with the various SCSI commands?